# SimpleJdbc, Invalid Conversion Requested

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbctemplate, simplejdbccall

Using Oracle database
This is my testMethod

```
public void testConnection(int a, int b) {
    this.jdbcTemplateObject = new JdbcTemplate(mysqlDataSource());
    SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplateObject).withCatalogName("packageName").withProcedureName("myProcedureName");

    SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("arg1", a);
    SqlParameterSource in2 = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("arg2", b);
      Map<String, Object> out = jdbcCall.execute(in,in2);
```

Below is my procedure

```
PROCEDURE get_misc_shipment_type (a  IN  NUMBER,
                                  b  IN  NUMBER,
                                  c  OUT VARCHAR2,
                                  d  OUT VARCHAR2);
```

My datasource connections are good and i verified database is being connected, but it throws this error,

```
callableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{call XX_RATELINX_SHIPPING_ENGINE.GET_MISC_SHIPMENT_TYPE(?, ?, ?, ?)}]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17132]; Invalid conversion requested; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid conversion requested
```

I am not getting what am i doing wrong, any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have to pass two more parameter, which can handle the output from procedure.  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/connector-j-en/connector-j-usagenotes-statements-callable.html

Comment: I got it resolved by changing this SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("arg1", a).addValue("arg2",b);

Comment: @vivek Do you have any idea, if the input argument passing should match exactly in stored procedure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it resolved by changing this :

```
SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("arg1", a).addValue("arg2",b);
```